# How to create a list of bytearrays?

Tags: python, arrays, list, byte

I need to determine the max. ASCII value of certain lines in a file. To avoid several conversions of the string into ASCII values, I would like to have a list of byte arrays beforehand.

I would like to read the lines of a file into a list of byte arrays. What's the best way to approach this?

If that's possible, I actually would like to have only every nth value as a byte array.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: You can use "readline" method on binary files, too, if the line ends with `\n`.

Comment: The documentation for the built-in [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function has an example of a block-reader function that reads a file in fixed-sized "chunks" of bytes. In a similar manner you could do use `for line in iter(my_file.readline, b""):` to read one by variable-length lines.